# Regex: Replacing last 4 numbers in an input with stars Regex

Tags: c#, regex, automapper

I currently need some help with Regex expressions in Automapper(C#).

I want to replace the last 4 (and 2 in another input) digits with the symbol *. Right now I only cover the last digit.

```
 .AfterMap((from, to) =>
                {
                    if (from.x!= null)
                        to.x= Regex.Replace(from.x, "[0-9]{2}$", "*");
                    if (from.y!= null)
                        to.y= Regex.Replace(from.y, "[0-9]{4}$", "*");
                })
```

Please help!

Comment: I would also look at using MapFrom, not AfterMap, that lets you put those functions into the member mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine and matching what you want.  However in both cases you're only inserting a single `*`.  Use:

```
.AfterMap((from, to) =>
            {
                if (from.x!= null)
                    to.x= Regex.Replace(from.x, "[0-9]{2}$", "**");
                if (from.y!= null)
                    to.y= Regex.Replace(from.y, "[0-9]{4}$", "****");
            })
```

Comment: So that was it? :O Just needed to add more "**" to each regex.replace? Thanks!

Comment: Yes - it will use the replacement parameter just once for each match.  Each match in this case being either two or four digits.

Comment: Your explanation of the code worked, but I need to be able to see the numbers in the admin part on my website. This function is affecting the x and y values everywhere. How do I specify it so it would only affect the web part of the project and not admin?

Comment: @eliinka sounds like you'll need to copy the values to be used in the admin side somewhere else away from the UI before you do this replace.  This replace isn't masking the values, it's actually changing them

Comment: yeah I meant changing not affecting. Hmm it could be tricky though. Admin and web part are connected in every way.

Answer (score 0):

As James Thorpe notice it the only problem is your replacement string.

So for the challenge: *One pattern to rule them all*

```
to.z = Regex.Replace(from.z, "[0-9]{2}(?=(?:[0-9]{2})?$)", "**");
```

Comment: Not entirely sure this is what the OP is after - they want to do two digits in some circumstances and four in others - this regex will always do four digits if available, two otherwise?  But yes - does seem rather redundant code being used that could probably be improved

Comment: @JamesThorpe: As I write in my answer, it's only for the challenge. If this way may have an interest, it will be to reuse a compiled pattern.

Comment: Fair enough!  Just wanted to highlight that it would result in different behaviour :)